# Manually Migrating from svn to git

Tags: git, git-svn

I am trying to migrate my svn repo from svn to git and it keeps on failing, it stops with the following output:

W: -empty_dir: trunk/ncontinuity2.core/extensions

When I do a `git branch -a`, it shows that it has not moved all the branches and indeed displays some branches that have been previously delted.

I have decide I can live without the history.

Is there anyway I can do this move manualy and recreate my branch structure in git?

I have tried git-svn and git2svn and both do not import my repo correctly, I just want to do it manually now.

Comment: Why do neither git-svn nor git2svn import your repository correctly? Perhaps that's the question that you should ask and get answered, as using either of those are much much easier than doing it all manually.

Comment: Agreed with CanSpice: What's the problem you're having, especially with svn2git? I've used that successfully on quite a few twisty nasty svn repos.

Comment: I posted this follow up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733524/git-svn-clone-or-svn2git-unexpectedly-stopping.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the working code, no history:

```
svn export <url> <other folder>
cd <other folder>
git init .
```

Comment: BUt this will not create git branches from the svn branches