# Git-svn W: -empty_dir warnings. What do they mean?

Tags: git, git-svn

While trying to clone an existing Subversion repository using git-svn using standard layout, I got a bunch of `W: -empty_dir` (and `W: +empty_dir`) warnings. The cloned git repository seems to be working, i.e. I can do usual git operations and dcommit to SVN repository.

The real problem is that the initial clone and rebase create some empty directories that do not exist in SVN repository, at the top of the repository (along with other directories in trunk). These directories contain no file but just some empty directories inside them. It seems that the "W: -empty_dir" warnings correspond to these empty directories.

I looked for empty directories by checking out the whole repository using SVN, but there is no empty directory. I also checked through SVN if the repository has files with special properties, but there was not any other than "executable" and "mime-type".

The existing repository was not originally following the standard layout, but I cleaned it up so that the top directories are just "trunk", "tags", and "branches".

What can be causing the creation of these empty directories that do not exist under Subversion?

Comment: `git config svn-remote.svn.automkdirs false` might stop `git svn` from recreating the directories.

Answer (score 20):

Without knowing exactly where those empty directories came from, you could tell `git-svn` to remove them by using the `--rmdir` command line option or `svn.rmdir` configuration option.

See [`git-svn` OPTIONS](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_options) man page and

> Remove directories from the SVN tree if there are no files left behind.
>   SVN can version empty directories, and they are not removed by default if there are no files left in them. git cannot version empty directories.
>   Enabling this flag will make the commit to SVN act like git.

---

The warning comes from SVN tags (which are "directories") not supported by git-svn, as in "[`git svn` interrupted, then I lost all the tags, how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11999914/6309)".
[From this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/msysgit/_iiD3DgNMk4/FPAa2QxjFFoJ):

> SVN tracks directories, git doesn't, so empty directories cannot be represented in git.
>   Those warnings on files seem to tell you which files that got deleted, causing an empty directory to be left in place, in that particular `svn commit` being imported.

The difference between `-empty_dir` and `+empty_dir` is about **how the empty directory appears in the SVN repo**:

#### `-empty_dir`

A bunch of files are deleted, leaving a directory (branch or tag) empty.

#### `+empty_dir`

An empty branch or tag has just been created in the SVN revision being imported, and `git-svn` won't import an empty directory.

---

Note that you [can restart the import after that warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11265799/6309).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but --rmdir option seems to delete empty directories when you dcommit. This would have been helpful if git-svn did not create these empty directories in the top directory (trunk).

Comment: @Barum: is there any possibility to remove them on the SVN side, in oder for the `git-svn` to operate without having to deal with them on the `dcommit` step?

Comment: Well, I would like to remove them, but the problem is that I can't find those empty directories in the SVN repository. (At least in the current snapshot.) I don't exactly know how git-svn works, but it maybe caused by empty directories in history?

Comment: @Barum: What is in your SVN checkout workspace? You do checkout '/'? (with `trunk`, `branches` and `tags` inside?). If you did checkout '/', clean it up and then made the `git-svn`, you could try to re-checkout the current cleaned SVN '/' repo, and redo the `git-svn` to see of the problem persists.

Comment: I've checked for empty directories on the whole repository, that is '/', but I could not find any. I couldn't even find the directories with the same name.

Comment: @Barum: strange. What are their names anyway? Maybe some kind of special directory?

Comment: No, they are not special. Although they don't exist in the current snapshot, it seems plausible that these directories existed in the past. Directory names include `src` and `Classes`. Oh well, I guess I just have to live with these empty directories. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Barum: What version of `git` and `git-svn` are you using, by the way? There was some `git svn` bugs related to empty directories with deleted parent like http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2009/12/8/18180

Comment: I am using 1.7.3.1. From the link, it seems that the patch should have been applied since earlier versions.

Comment: no one explained the difference between /-empty_dir and +empty_dir?

Comment: @shigazaru good point. I have edited my answer to make that difference (between `-empty_dir` and `+empty_dir`) more apparent and explicit.

Comment: The --preserve-empty-dirs option can be used to track otherwise empty directories.Since git tracks files not directories it creates an empty dummy file in the directory (.gitignore by default) to force the directory to exist.

Answer (score 8):

One of the things with git is that it does not track directories. It is all about content (files) in git. So empty directories are pretty much left to languish in your local repo. The best way to get rid of empty directories in your local repo is to do git clean -d.

Checkout man git clean for more info.

Comment: Yes, empty directories are probably the cause. But, if I remember correctly, the directories were no longer existent in the subversion repo. My best guess is that when git builds up history by importing all the commits, empty directories there somehow do not get cleaned up. Possibly a bug in git-svn.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the question in the title (which is what draws google's attention to this page), according to my findings, using either git-svn 1.7.1 or git 1.8.5: the warning `W: -empty_dir: x/y/z` means that the file or folder x/y/z was removed in the SVN changeset. Unless you specified -q (--quiet), that fact was already reported as `D x/y/z`. What I think it tries to say is that as a consequence, the folder x/y *might* have become empty and was therefore removed from the git view. It is far more common that x/y did not become empty and there is nothing peculiar going on.

In practice, if removing x/y/z would have left x/y empty, you would probably have removed the whole of x/y in the SVN changeset, and the removal of x/y/z would not even be reported separately. So you would not get that warning, but instead `W: -empty_dir: x/y` warns you that x might have become empty, which you know it didn't because then you would have deleted x...

If, on the other hand, you did leave empty directories around and want to keep them, I guess you would use --preserve-empty-dirs and I see no point in the warning either (if it still appears in that case).

So in short, ignore it. Unlike `W: +empty_dir`, which is a different story.