# Why is git creating empty directory: build

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

Why is git creating empty directory: build.

I am cloning a SVN repo with the following commands

```
git svn clone -s http://svn/java/project project
```

and I see that git created a empty directory that I don't see in SVN, I keep removing it but everytime I do a

```
git svn rebase
```

it comes back.. can someone please tell me why and how to stop it

Comment: You're probably being hit by this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147356/git-svn-w-empty-dir-warnings-what-do-they-mean.

Comment: you maybe right but after reading all that I still don't understand how to fix it

Comment: I suspect you'll have to `git svn clone` again using the `--rmdir` option.

Comment: Have you tried a `git log --name-status build`, to see what's going on?

Comment: Try to remove the directory using the official Subversion client and only then clone with git-svn --rmdir

Comment: `git config svn-remote.svn.automkdirs false` might stop `git svn` from recreating the directories.